# What is the deal with modifying the volatile boolean field of an object, while holding the specific monitor, when lazy locking?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, visibility

I implemented a lazy locked list, that supports the following methods: boolean add(T item), boolean remove(T item), boolean contains(T item).

For example the add method:

```
@Override
public boolean add(T item) {
    int key = item.hashCode();

    while(true){
        Node pred = head;
        Node curr = pred.next;

        while(curr.key < key) { pred = curr; curr = curr.next; }

        pred.Lock.lock();
        curr.Lock.lock();

        try{
            if(!pred.marked && !curr.marked && pred.next == curr){
                if(curr.key == key){ return false; }
                else{ Node insertMe = new Node(item); insertMe.next = curr; pred.next = insertMe; return true; }
            }
        } finally{ pred.Lock.unlock(); curr.Lock.unlock(); }
    }
}
```

Where the Node object has a volatile boolean field "marked", set to false by default. The lock of a node is a reentrant one. A node marked true is considered already being removed by the remove method. However why is this even relevant, when the specific object's monitor is anyway held by the specific thread? In other words, will it even occur at any time, that a thread is acquiring an object's lock and then seeing that node being marked as removed?

Edit:
The contains method obviously doesn't lock at all, however is the purpose for marking the node considered deleted just to be able to make a contains check? Is it therefore necessary to declare the marked field volatile?

contains:

```
    @Override
public boolean contains(T item) {
    int key = item.hashCode();

    while(true){
        Node curr = head;

        while(curr.key < key) { curr = curr.next; }

        if(curr.key == key && !curr.marked) return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

remove:

```
    @Override
public boolean remove(T item) {
    int key = item.hashCode();

    while(true){
        Node pred = head;
        Node curr = pred.next;

        while(curr.key < key) { pred = curr; curr = curr.next; }

        pred.Lock.lock();
        curr.Lock.lock();

        try{
            if(!pred.marked && !curr.marked && pred.next == curr){
                if(curr.key != key) { return false; }
                else{
                    curr.marked = true;
                    pred.next = curr.next;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } finally{ pred.Lock.unlock(); curr.Lock.unlock(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the `marked` is required for the contains method and not for the add method. My guess is that the `marked`-check in the add function does absolutely nothing.

The `marked` field absolutely must be volatile, because the JIT reserves the right to re-order the code if that would provide a benefit. The only guarantee is that any code before any manipulation of a volatile field has been completely executed before the volatile field is changed (happens-before relationship).

So in your code above if the field was not volatile, the JIT could decide to make a thread-local copy of `marked` in the thread that calls 'contains', and later checks against that local version of `marked`, which is however probably outdated at that point. In this case running `contains` and `remove` at the same time could cause a race condition.

As a side-note it should be mentioned that Collections from the Concurrent package solve all these issues much more elegant (and without bugs), and therefore should be preferred in all cases. If you duplicate a class that already exists in the standard library, you usually implement it worse.

Comment: The whole thing is just for practicing and better concurrency understanding purpose, thanks though for the side-note. The marked explanation seems legit, but are you sure about the add? For example if thread t1 iterates through the list, now has a local pred and curr with their references, before this add t1 thread can lock both pred and curr, t2 removed the node where t1's pred still has the reference on. If the pred wasn't marked now, wouldn't t1 just check for curr.key == key and consider the check correct, although the node referenced by t1's pred is already removed?

Comment: That is correct. However in multi-threading the request for `contains` is always outdated the moment you receive the answer. It is however not causing a threading issue, so it is not incorrect, just not very helpful either.

Comment: The `marked` check in the `add` method is required, because the method is iterating to the node *before* acquiring the lock, so it is possible that a concurrently running `remove` operation did not complete at this point. In that case, `add` would hold a reference to a node that has been removed by the time it has the lock. Since this is a very rare case, the code solves this by simply unlocking and repeating the entire operation.